# Dynamic arrays as texture GLSL

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, textures, dynamic-arrays

I have worked with C++/OpenSceneGraph/GLSL integration and I need to handle dynamic array on shader.

My dynamic data array of `vec3` was converted into 1D-texture to pass as `uniform` to fragment (I'm using GLSL 1.3), as follows:

```
osg::ref_ptr<osg::Image> image = new osg::Image; 
image->setImage(myVec3Array->size(), 1, 1, GL_RGBA8, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, (unsigned char*) &myVec3Array[0], osg::Image::NO_DELETE);

// Pass the texture to GLSL as uniform
osg::StateSet* ss = scene->getOrCreateStateSet();
ss->addUniform( new osg::Uniform("vertexMap", texture) );
```

For now, I would like to retrieve my raw array of `vec3` on fragment shader. How can I do this process? Does a `texture2D` function only return normalized values?

Comment: Is `myVec3Array` a STL vector?

Comment: @Matso, `myVec3Array` is a `osg::Vec3Array`, however I'm not sure if this datatype uses pure STL.

Answer (score 1):

> Does a texture2D function only return normalized values?

No. It returns values depedning on the [internal format](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Image_Format) of the texture.

> ```
> image->setImage(myVec3Array->size(), 1, 1, GL_RGBA8, GL_RGBA, GL_FLOAT, (unsigned char*) &myVec3Array[0], osg::Image::NO_DELETE);
>                                            ^^^^^^^^
> ```

`GL_RGBA8` is an unsigned *normalized* integer format ("UNORM" for short). So the values in the texture are unsigned integers with 8 bit per channel, and `[0,255]` is mapped to `[0,1]` when sampling the texture.

If you want unnormalized floats, you must use some appropriate format, like `GL_RGBA32F`.

Comment: Thank you so much, @derhass. One additional question: do you know how can I retrieve these values on GLSL side?

Comment: Like any other values. If you have a `GL_RGBA32F` texture, the `texture` and `texelFetch` GLSL functions will just directly return the values from the texture.

Comment: I guess I got some problems with texture coordinates. Please could you give me an example?

Comment: OK, this code might be a very confusing, but it will demonstrate the point: [example with standard `GL_RGB` texture](https://www-user.tu-chemnitz.de/~heinm/tmp/HelloTexture.c), and the [modified for `GL_RGB32F` version](https://www-user.tu-chemnitz.de/~heinm/tmp/HelloTexture_float.c). Note the only differences are the data type and intializers for `img`, the `glTexImage2D` call, and the fragment shader. In the float versison, I use the value range `[0,10]` in the texture, and I multiply the sampled value with `0.1` in the fragment shader to get color output in `[0,1]` again, for demo purposes.